# Does WCF support any kind of resume functionality?

Tags: wcf, resume

I am using WCF to upload data to a server.

If the communication fails, is there any way to resume the upload?

Answer (score 1):

Chunking channel fits your scenario especially when sending large messages.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the wsHttpBinding protocol supports what is called "reliable sessions", where intermittent network blackouts can be caught and handled. The sender might need to resend certain bits of the information, but basically, this will give you a certain level of safety.

Check out Michele Leroux Bustamante's 15-part series "[WCF Top To Bottom](http://www.dasblonde.net/WCFWebcastSeries.aspx)" for more information - installment no. 12 deals specifically with [Reliable Messaging](http://www.dasblonde.net/ct.ashx?id=c639724e-3ae5-4e8b-9d3f-d4e42dea41e6&url=http%3a%2f%2fmsevents.microsoft.com%2fCUI%2fEventDetail.aspx%3fEventID%3d1032344353%26Culture%3den-US).

Or check out the MSDN [introduction to reliable messaging in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480191.aspx).

Marc